# fade div on desktop and OR mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `div` (`fademe`) that I need to show every time a user `hover's` a mouse on another `div`.

The problem is that there is no `hover` for mobile browsers and I'm having a hard time to get a working solution for every devices.

T**his is my code working on desktop devices:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```js
$("body").on("mouseover touchstart", ".parent", function(e) {
  $("#fademe").addClass("show");
});
$("body").on("mouseout touchend", ".parent", function(e) {
  $("#fademe").removeClass("show");
});
```

```css
#fademe {
  color:#000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="parent">

    <div id="fademe"> »» here «« </div>

  </div>
</body>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Eh, what's up doc?</title>
<style>
.fademe {text-align:center;
font-size:14px;
float:right;
margin:0 25px;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition:opacity 5s;
-moz-transition:opacity 5s;
-o-transition:opacity 5s;
transition:opacity 5s;}

.show {opacity:1;
-webkit-transition:opacity 5s;
-moz-transition:opacity 5s;
-o-transition:opacity 5s;
transition:opacity 5s;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="fademe"> »» here «« </div>

<script>
$("body").hover(
  function () {
    $(".fademe").addClass("show"); 
  },
  function () {
    $(".fademe").removeClass("show");
  }
);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about adding/removing the classes, if a specific element is visible using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) on mobile devices?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `touchstart` and `touchend` events for mobile.

```
 $('body').on('mouseover touchstart', '#idOfMyElement', function(e){ });   
 $('body').on('mouseout touchend', '#idOfMyElement', function(e){ });
```

Comment: tried your solution but it's not working. Can you make and `fiddle` example, please?

Comment: share your solution on fiddle, i will check what you are doing

Comment: above there's a snippet